# does an animation always return to its starting point in java?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make an `ImageView` **spin** around and it always goes back to its original position after the animation is done.

Is there a way to make it stop or to make it, say, stop upside down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this method for your animation: [setFillAfter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setFillAfter%28boolean%29)